# C++ Programming - Calculating recurrent increases

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Effective January 1st of each year, Gabby recieves a 5% raise on her previous year's salary. She wants a program that calculates and displays the amount of her annual raises for the next three years. The program also should calculate and display her total salary for the three years.

I have to test the program and this is what i get but when i desk check it comes out wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
const double RATE = .05;
double salary = 0.0; 
double raise = 0.0;
double totalSalary = 0.0; 

cout << "Enter the salary:";
cin >> salary;

for(int counter = 0; counter <=3; counter++)
{ 
cout <<salary<<endl;
raise = (salary * 0.05);


}

return 0;
} //end of main function
```

Comment: When your question is answered, do **not** delete your question, or edit it to say "thank you". Instead, hit the checkmark next to the answer you like best, and reward the person who posted it with a little bit of a reputation bonus.

Answer (score 2):

You're not adding the raise to the salary:

```
salary += raise;
```

Comment: Good catch.  Also, she's not calculating the cumulative salary either.  Neither the raise nor the cumulative pay are being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

This one is a little more accurate.  It will calculate with decimals without rounding and post the raise for each year, then add how much the total of her raises will be over three years.  Also, some notes are added so you know what was going on in the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//declare variables
double salary = 0.0;
double totalSalary = 0.0;
const double RATE = 0.05;

//input
cout << "Enter the salary: ";
cin >> salary;
cout << endl;

//loop for years and calculation
for(int numYears = 1; numYears <= 3; numYears ++)
{
cout << fixed;
cout << setprecision(2);
salary = salary*(1+RATE);
cout << "Year " << numYears;
cout << ": $" << salary << endl;
//end for
}

cout << "The total salary over three years is $" << totalSalary << endl;
cout << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you declare a constant called `RATE` (which should really be at the top of the program rather than in your main function) but don't bother to use this in your calculation.  Instead you use the hard-coded value of `0.05`.

Second, you're not adding the calculation to the `salary` variable.  You can use `salary += raise` or `salary *= (1.0 + RATE)`.

Third, you're not doing anything with the `totalSalary` variable at all.

Your code should look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const double RATE = 0.05;

int main()
{
    double salary = 0.0; 
    double totalSalary = 0.0; 

    cout << "Enter the salary:" << endl;
    cin >> salary;

    for(int counter = 0; counter <=3; counter++)
    { 
        cout << salary << endl;
        salary *= (1.0 + RATE);\
        totalSalary += salary;
    }

    cout << "The total salary is " << totalSalary << endl;

    return 0;
}
```