# Sum of even integers problem

Tags: visual-c++

I need to create a program that displays the sum of the even integers between and including two numbers entered by the user.

This is what I have so far and it's not working!?

So point me in the right direction please!

```
//Advanced30.cpp - displays the sum of the even integers between and 
//including two numbers entered by the user
//Created/revised by <your name> on <current date>

#

    include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        // declare variables
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        int sum= 0;

        cout << "Enter the First Number:" << endl;  
        cin >> num1;     
        cout << "Enter the Second Number:" << endl;    
        cin >> num2;      


        for (num2 = num1; num1 <= num2; num1 += 2) sum += num1;       
        num1 = num1 % 2 == 0 ? num1 : num1+1; 
        num2 = num2 % 2 == 0 ? num2 : num2-1;

        return 0;
```

Comment: How about using a good debugger? If you are on windows and using Visual Studio, put a break-point after main and step through your program, you will realize what you are doing wrong.

Comment: move your `for` loop after `num2 = num2 % 2 == 0 ? num2 : num2-1;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Programming help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386477/c-programming-help)

Comment: ... or if a debugger is not available, try debug tracing.

Comment: @user670580 : Whats wrong with you? Asking the same question again and again.

Comment: I know one solution without any loop! Use 1+3+5+...+(2n-1) = n^2

Comment: Not trying to be insensitive, but you would have found the problem yourself, and faster, if you had written the code neatly (with indentation, braces, and words) in the first place.  Such things are available for your own benefit; it's only a shortcut if you get there faster.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do EXACTLY what your computer is doing when it's doing the loop. Do it on a paper. Keep track of num2, num1 and their value.
You'll see very quickly where the problem is.

Comment: This. Do this and you'll figure out what's wrong with the code and learn about debugging in the process.

Answer (score 0):

try the Loop

```
for(; num1<=num2;num1++)
{
if(num1%2==0)
 sum=sum+num1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     for (num2 = num1; num1 <= num2; num1 += 2) sum += num1;
> ```

You've overwritten your stop-point. :)

I would also suggest more meaningful names:

```
int start=0;
int real_start=0;
int stop=0;
int sum=0;

/* ... */

real_start = (start % 2) ? start+1 : start;

for (int i = real_start; i <= stop; i+=2) sum += i;

/* ... */
```